# Centos 7 how to instal old epel repository to get php5 mssql_* functions

Tags: sql-server, centos7, vesta, epel

I need to install web server for older intranet app - it requires `mssql` library (I know its old, but nobody will redevelop the app).

In Centos 7 I was installing it like this (along with vesta - also old)

```
yum install epel-release
yum install php-mssql
```

And that is it - it worked great, but now while I try to install it it says `mssql` was removed and replaced with pdo.

I tried to install the `mssql` library directly:

```
sudo yum install wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/php-mssql-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

But there was a problem with dependencies I could not solve (It requires X and X require Y and then Z.... and so on).

My idea is not to install newest epel release but to download older one install it. Is it possible? I have found old repository but how to install it? (its list of modules, how do I install them all to get dependencies)

```
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/
```

Or maybe there is other idea to install `mssql` functions?